# Not receiving email when someone is clicking on pay now btn

Tags: php, html, css

I am new to PHP building a website with paytm gateway integration. I have register page with pay now but when someone clicks on pay now it is directing them to pgRedirect.php (provided by paytm). I want if someone clicks on pay now but we should get an email about all the details filled by cust in register page

```
<?php
header("Pragma: no-cache");
header("Cache-Control: no-cache");
header("Expires: 0");
// following files need to be included
require_once("lib/config_paytm.php");
require_once("lib/encdec_paytm.php");

$NAME = $_POST['NAME'];
$EMAIL = $_POST['EMAIL'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$model = $_POST['model'];
$add = $_POST['add'];
$ORDER_ID = $_POST['ORDER_ID'];
$TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST['TXN_AMOUNT'];

$sub = "enquiry from customer details";

$msg='';
$msg.="Name : $NAME <br>\r\n";
$msg.="EMAIL : $EMAIL <br>\r\n";
$msg.="Phone : $phone <br>\r\n";   
$msg.="Model : $model <br>\r\n";
$msg.="Add : $add<br>\r\n";
$msg.="ORDER_ID : $ORDER_ID<br>\r\n";
$msg.="TXN_AMOUNT : $TXN_AMOUNT <br>\r\n";

$to = 'abhi.singh779@gmail.com';

    $headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
    $headers .='From: abhi.singh779@gmail.com'."\r\n";
    $headers .="Bcc: ".$emailList."\r\n";
    $headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";


    $mail=mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);


$checkSum = "";
$paramList = array();

$ORDER_ID = $_POST["ORDER_ID"];
$CUST_ID = $_POST["CUST_ID"];
$INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID = $_POST["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"];
$CHANNEL_ID = $_POST["CHANNEL_ID"];
$TXN_AMOUNT = $_POST["TXN_AMOUNT"];

// Create an array having all required parameters for creating checksum.
$paramList["MID"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_MID;
$paramList["ORDER_ID"] = $ORDER_ID;
$paramList["CUST_ID"] = $CUST_ID;
$paramList["INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID"] = $INDUSTRY_TYPE_ID;
$paramList["CHANNEL_ID"] = $CHANNEL_ID;
$paramList["TXN_AMOUNT"] = $TXN_AMOUNT;
$paramList["WEBSITE"] = PAYTM_MERCHANT_WEBSITE;
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = 'pgResponse.php';//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["EMAIL"] = $_POST["EMAIL"]; // customer email id
$paramList["MOBILE_NO"] = $_POST['phone']; // customer 10 digit mobile no.
/*$paramList["NAME"] = $_POST["name"];//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["EMAIL"] = $_POST["email"];//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["PHONE"] = $_POST["phone"];//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["MODEL"] = $_POST["model"];//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["CALLBACK_URL"] = $_POST["name"];//Provided by Paytm
$paramList["ADDRESS"] = $_POST["add"];//Provided by Paytm*/


//$paramList["MSISDN"] = $MSISDN; //Mobile number of customer
//$paramList["MERC_UNQ_REF"] =  $_POST['email'];
//$paramList["VERIFIED_BY"] = "EMAIL"; //
//$paramList["IS_USER_VERIFIED"] = "YES"; //



//Here checksum string will return by getChecksumFromArray() function.
$checkSum = getChecksumFromArray($paramList,PAYTM_MERCHANT_KEY);

?>
<html>
 <head>
 <title>Merchant Check Out Page</title>
 </head>
 <body>
    <center><h1>Please do not refresh this page...</h1></center>
        <form method="post" action="<?php echo PAYTM_TXN_URL ?>" name="f1">
        <table border="1">
            <tbody>
            <?php
            foreach($paramList as $name => $value) {
                echo '<input type="hidden" name="' . $name .'" value="' . $value . '">';
            }
            ?>
            <input type="hidden" name="CHECKSUMHASH" value="<?php echo $checkSum ?>">enter code here
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            document.f1.submit();
        </script>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post your code .

Comment: Where is your code ?

Comment: @Hkachhia sir cheek the code

Comment: `pgResponse.php` this is page where you get response from Paytm on the basic of this you need to write custom mail sending code

Comment: I believed your SMTP configuration is correct in php. Now you need to check the response of $mail. See this tutorial and verify your mail is successfully send or not. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_sending_emails.htm

Comment: @ParitoshMahale yes sir I have wrote customized code but email is not going.

Answer (score 0):

Your mail function

```
$mail=mail($to, $sub, $msg, $headers);
```

remove header from it

```
$mail=mail($to, $sub, $msg);
```

now try

Comment: did it still not getting mail